# Pentaho j_spring_security_check Internal Server Error

Tags: pentaho

I am unable to login on Pentaho although i am using correct username and password. Rather it says "Pentaho j_spring_security_check Internal Server Error" in **Enterprise Edition**. After fresh installation this error is resolved but same error arises when i restart my PC.
Please help

Comment: check the logs and you'll see the real reason for the error. Probably your solution repository database (postgres) is not up?

Comment: There are different exceptions in pentaho.log i just googled but found not any exact solution

Answer (score 0):

This was a license expiration issue. Contact Pentaho for license management if you face this issue.